# Swift_TransportException: Cannot send message without a sender address - Notification only

Tags: laravel

I'm having a strange issue with Laravel using Notifications. At the moment, my mail config is set to use sendmail which is working fine when I send out emails directly. I wanted to set forgotten password notifications to use the queue functionality using ShouldQueue:

`class CustomResetPasswordNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue`

when doing so my jobs fail with the above error:

`Swift_TransportException: Cannot send message without a sender address`

If I remove the `implements ShouldQueue` it sends the email fine but obviously bypasses the queue.

My .env file has everything correctly set

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=**ouremail**
MAIL_FROM_NAME=**ourbusinessname**
```

It's like the queue isn't reading the config file properly, has anybody come across this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After update the `.env` did you clear your config? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i did yeah unfortunately it didn't work. I checked the actual cache config file to verify and also Config::get('mail') to be sure.